# UITableView sections Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

So I have two different `UITableViewController` which are segued to from the same `UITableViewController`, just with a different method call, and both classes contain almost identical code and segues to the Controller. Could someone explain to me why these look so different? How do I fix it to make the first image look like the cleaner, more organised second image.

[image: Image 1]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of styles of tables in iOS: plain and grouped. On the first screenshot you have plain-styled table view, and grouped on the second screenshot.

You can set style of table view in your storyboard:

[image: How to choose UITableView style]

**Updated.**

Also you can set style programmaticaly: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/style

Comment: how have I missed that? Thank you so much Alex :)